# Understanding why I'm still getting CS8618 Error In Constructor

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm getting to grips with the nullable change, but I've hit something that's giving CS8618 (Nullable field must contain non-null) but I don't think it should be.

Basically I have a private field, and my constructor calls an 'init/setup etc' method, the method does set the private field, but it's not happy.

i.e.

```
    public class Test
    {
        private object bob;

        public Test()
        {
            Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            bob = new object();
        }
    }
```

The compiler highlights the constructor as being in error.  Can I tell it somehow that `Init()` does what it wants? or is there something I'm missing that means that `Init()` might not be called in some situations which would make the warning valid?

I've tried a few `!` at the end in places, but that doesn't seem to be it. If I move the code from `Init()` into the constructor the error does go away in this trivial example and the one in my code.

Comment: You must set the value in the constructor.

Comment: Add `[MemberNotNull(nameof(bob))]` to `Init` and Bob's your non-nullable uncle. Static analysis is not yet clever enough to figure out such things on its own.

Comment: [For more details on `MemberNotNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#helper-methods-membernotnull-and-membernotnullwhen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @Jeroen Mostert's comment, the solution is to add an attribute `MemberNotNull` to the child method, like so:

```
    public class Test
    {
        private object bob;

        public Test()
        {
            Init();
        }

        [MemberNotNull(nameof(bob))]
        private void Init()
        {
            bob = new object();
        }
    }
```

Note that future versions of C# may make this unnecessary.